# AWS security groups

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I have a single active EC2 instance making requests via a Python script. There is a security group attached to this particular instance with SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS communication with ONLY sources and traffic allowed for my IP address.

For each request made via the Python script, there is a successful response received that I can then analyze. This is confusing and unexpected as this response should be blocked by my security group as it is generated and sent from another IP address via HTTP or HTTPS protocol. Why are these responses being successfully received by instance and code?

**EDIT 1**:

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: Hi can you provide more information on your security groups rules?

Comment: You said the EC2 instance is making requests via a Python script in the first paragraph, then you said the Python script is making requests to the EC2 instance in the second paragraph. Please clarify the source and destination of the specific network traffic you are trying to block or allow, and provide all inbound and outbound rules of the security group assigned to your EC2 instance. Also, I recommend reading up on the "statefulness" of security groups https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - images have been included to supplement my question. These images show the security group details for the EC2 instance my Python script is running from - this code is making requests to remote servers and successfully receiving responses.

Comment: So to confirm your IP address is not one of those IP addresses?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion - my IP address is all three of those. No other IP address is listed and thus allowed.

Comment: So you're running a python script from elsewhere to do a health check on this instance?

Comment: Nope - from this instance, I have a Python script running making requests to a remote website server at (for example IP 1.2.3.4) and successfully recieving responses from the server. No health checks going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security groups are stateful. Response to an http request is sent in the same tcp connection, so it will not be blocked, because your ec2 instance initiated the connection (see the tcp connection lifecycle).

Should another component try to connect (initiate a connection) to your instance from outside of your allowed IPs, it would be blocked.